# Backward compatibility in Sencha

Tags: mobile-website

As i am going to develop mobile web app for all devices. My question is, if the browser is not support html5 kind of stuff, Whether Sencha will support HTML4?

Thanks in advance,

srini

Comment: you can answer now, i accepted some of the answers for my previous post.

Answer (score 1):

[sencha person] @Sri. Sencha Touch works on Android 2.1 and Apple iOS ONLY for release 1.0, and will be supporting RIM, Nokia etc. devices as they add modern browsers to their phones that can support javascript and CSS at reasonable performance and correctness.

[Update: We've tested the new RIM Blackberry Torch, and will be adding it to our support list - probably in release 1.1]

A majority of existing phones (Nokia featurephones etc.) are not capable of running a web **application** because they lack javascript performance, CSS support and even full HTML capabilities. In our (opinionated) view, the only phones (today) that can support a proper web app experience are Android 2.1+ and Apple iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I cannot give a definitive answer, but given that ExtJS (the name until recently) still supports Internet Explorer 6, I'd guess so.  They are double-licensed as GPL + proprietary license, so cannot just drop support for something outdated since that would piss some/many paying customers.